# How does django cache_page expire?

Tags: django, caching

- You set cache_page(60sec) for an endpoint,
- We assume the endpoint is requested every 5 sec

Does the cache reset the timer for expiration every 5 sec , resulting in never expiring cache?

Or does it expire after 60sec?

Answer (score 0):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}
```

First, I am not sure which cache backend you using, but in general case.
When TIMEOUT is None, the cache will not expire.